# How to mount connected USB external HDD in CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, usb, usb-drive, fdisk

All of the guides I've found say the first thing to do is to run fdisk -l, to identify the disk.  Sadly it doesn't seem to show up on fdisk for me.

Next I checked dmesg, which gives this output:

```
[1829673.163946] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[1829673.330949] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=231a, bcdDevice= 7.10
[1829673.331253] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[1829673.331550] usb 2-1.2: Product: Expansion
[1829673.331726] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Seagate
[1829673.331915] usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: NAQA173V
[1829673.582129] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[1829673.592637] scsi host7: uas
[1829673.592888] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[1829673.593487] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  Expansion        0710 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[1829673.608218] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg10 type 0
[1829683.577777] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdk] Spinning up disk...
[1829685.655224] usb 2-1.2: stat urb: status -71
[1829685.680719] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 3
[1829685.681045] sd 7:0:0:0: tag#0 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD
[1829685.681278] sd 7:0:0:0: tag#0 CDB: Test Unit Ready 00 00 00 00 00 00
[1829685.089672] .ready
[1829685.771696] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdk] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[1829685.772015] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdk] Sense not available.
[1829685.861690] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdk] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[1829685.862012] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdk] Sense not available.
[1829685.927692] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdk] Write Protect is off
[1829685.927874] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdk] Mode Sense: 00 00 00 00
[1829685.957690] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdk] Asking for cache data failed
[1829685.957889] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdk] Assuming drive cache: write through
[1829686.131686] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdk] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[1829686.131994] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdk] Sense not available.
[1829686.221684] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdk] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[1829686.222002] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdk] Sense not available.
[1829686.401685] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdk] Attached SCSI disk
```

Does that look ok?  What should I be doing next given that fdisk doesn't work?  Is `[sdk]` in that output telling me the disk exists on /dev/sdk?

Thank you

Comment: And now I've tried a reboot it doesn't even show up in dmesg.  This is a remote box, so I can't physically unplug/reconnect it without being charged €20 by staff at the datacenter...

Comment: What output gives`fdisk -l`? Does `mount|grep sdk` give some output?

Comment: `fdisk -l` just lists the ten 6TB drives inside the system, it doesn't mention the 4TB USB drive at all.  And now that I've rebooted, the USB doesn't even show up on `dmesg`, so it doesn't suprise me that `mount|grep sdk` gives nothing useful :-(